# Get a range of cells with all cell attributes

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to get a range of cells with all the cell 'attributes' such as value, cell backgroud color, cell font etc. in one go and then store it in an array.

Rather then iterating over the range multiple times and getting each individual attribute one at a time?

For Example this would be the intent, though I know it doesn't work:

```
Dim cellData() As Variant
cellData= Range("A36:W36")
Debug.Print cellData(1,1).Value
Debug.Print cellData(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can tbh.  If you are after storing the current colour states of each cell, i'd suggest copying the row/range to another sheet.

Comment: @DaveMac - it should be possible, just create a multi-dimension array and use the different dimensions to store a part of the cell's info. (Working on something now).

Comment: without iterating through a range am not sure, id tried arr = Range("B2:B5").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex where arr is a variant.

Comment: What is the end goal? All the values are contained within the range object - you can access them directly from there, so what exactly is it you want to do with this array once you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I did kinda quick to see if it's on the right path:

```
Sub addToArray()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim cellAttributes()
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer

' We're going to store 2 cells' attributes.  We're going to use 3 attributes, hence the next line
ReDim cellAttributes(1 To 2, 1 To 3) ' since you want Value, Font, and Color, I chose up to three. Change this if you want more attributes
'The array will be cellAttributes([Cell Address],{value, font, color})

Set rng = Range("A1:A2")
i = 1
k = 1
For Each cel In rng
    cellAttributes(i, k) = cel.Value
    cellAttributes(i, k + 1) = cel.Font.Name
    cellAttributes(i, k + 2) = cel.Interior.ColorIndex
    Debug.Print "Cell " & cel.Address & " has a value of: " & cellAttributes(i, 1) & ", font: " & cellAttributes(i, 2) & " and bg color index: " & cellAttributes(i, 3)
    i = i + 1
    k = 1
Next cel


End Sub
```

After reading your question a little more carefully, what exactly are you trying to do?  The above macro will look at each cell at a time, then apply the attributes to an array, before moving on.  Of course, you can make this more dynamic (I used more "magic numbers" than I'm comfortable with, but I just wanted to make sure this is (or isn't) what you're looking for).